# How do you sketch a $\cos x + \cos y$ graph?

Tags: trigonometry, curves

This question is related to standing waves from physics, but mostly contains math.

Let,
$y_1 = A \cos {( \alpha t + k )}$
$y_2 = A \cos (\beta t + c )$ where $k,c$ are arbitrary, real constants.

How would you sketch $y_3=y_1+y_2$?

Using the appropriate trigonometric identity, we can simplify this to -

$y_3 = 2A \cos \bigg( \dfrac {(αt + k)+(βt + c)} { 2}\bigg ) \cos \bigg( \dfrac {(αt + k)-(βt + c)} { 2} \bigg)$

But, I don't know how to proceed from there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With different frequencies, there's not much you can do other than plot points and draw a curve between them. With the same frequency and different phases, it's possible to combine them into one sinusoid with a different amplitude (just use the identity you wrote, the second factor is constant in this scenario), which is then easy to sketch.

Comment: @Ian if you don't mind could elaborate on what you meant in the second part? If  it helps, this is the question I had in mind when posting this ( q.18 part b ) : https://www.physicsandmathstutor.com/admissions/pat/solutions-2017/

Comment: Since the wavelengths are similar in that question, it *basically* looks like a single sinusoid with frequency $\frac{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_1}+\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_2}}{2}$ but with an amplitude that changes on length scales on the order of $\left | \frac{1}{\lambda_1}-\frac{1}{\lambda_2} \right |^{-1}$.

Comment: It's a bit confusing for me, but thank you very much for the help.